# How do I implement a .diff changeset from core.trac.wordpress.org locally?

Tags: php, core, customization, svn, version-control

I have a local copy of the latest version of wordpress that I set up using

```
svn co http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/
```

There is a diff that I want to pull into my local fileset:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/19371/19371.diff

Is this something that I can do with subversion? What commands do I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you need is `patch` which is not specific to SVN. It's really easy to do. See this article: http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html

Answer (score 1):

Change to the directory, download the patch (.diff file), then apply it using the `patch` command:

```
cd /var/www/wp-includes/ #use your wp-includes directory here
wget http://core.trac.wordpress.org/raw-attachment/ticket/19416/19416.diff
patch class-wp-admin-bar.php < 19416.diff
```

Check that it worked ok and then remove the `19416.diff` file.